# Make redirections based on user role

Tags: wordpress, function, user-controls, wordpress-theming, user-roles

In my website I want to have custom user roles. I created the user roles, but when I make the redirections accordingly those are not working. Only working admin role and subscriber role. Custom user roles are not working. This is my code. Can somebody help me with this.

```
function disable_dashboard_access() {
    if( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in()  && ( current_user_can('upload_users') || current_user_can('upload_videos') ) ) {
            wp_redirect(home_url('/dashboard/'));
            exit;
        } elseif ( is_user_logged_in()  && ( current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('contributor') ) ) {
            wp_redirect(home_url('/my-account/'));
            exit;
        } else {
            wp_redirect(home_url('/login/'));
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action('init','disable_dashboard_access');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect user by role

```
function wpsp_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user){
        global $user;
        if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles))
        {
            if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) //check for admins
            {
                return $redirect_to; // redirect them to the default place
            }
            else
            {
                return site_url('/wp-admin/admin.php?page=sch-dashboard');
            }
        }
        return $redirect_to;
    }
    add_filter('login_redirect', 'wpsp_login_redirect', 10, 3);
```